Is the spark plan optimized? Unusal long time for computation
Hi i have 2 pyspark classes.
From class main -> i have one df, mydict=df,
from class attr (mydict is common in both class), i am doing df=mydict
then computing attribute df.withColumn -> approx 15-20 withColumn chained to generate my attribute.
force evaluation here
at the end mydict=df  -> problamatic line.
But when i add above line, spark gets stuck and sometimes takes hour to start evaluation.
When i remove that line it takes 5-10 minutes which i feel still more than expected.
below is plan
enter image description here
What am i doing wrong. there is sufficient resources given and i reparititoned my data to my coresx2 and also persisted df at the beginning.
I have lots of chain withColumn just this attribute takes so long other i compute around 400 such attribute and all completed in 40 minutes.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
